# A metric space with sufficient points(dense enough)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces

I say that a metric space $X$ is *dense enough* if $\forall r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x\in X, r_1<r_2 \Rightarrow B(x,r_1)\subsetneqq B(x,r_2)$. That is, $B(x,r)$ is strictly increasing with $r$ for any point $x$ in metric space $X$.

**Questions**

1. Is there a formal name for *dense enough*?
2. Is it true that all *dense enough* metric spaces are complete?
3. Are there any article or literature about such metric space?
4. Can a *dense enough* metric space be embeded *canonically* (perhaps isometry) into a Banach space?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is an example of an incomplete "dense enough" metric space.  At the very least, the set cannot have any isolated points.  But this does not go far enough as the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of two closed disks separated by a distance has no isolated points but is not "dense enough".

Comment: $A\subset B$ does NOT mean that $A$ is proper subset of $B$. I edited your Q from \subset to \subsetneqq/

Comment: Another way to say the metric space $(X,d)$ is dense enough is that $D(x)=\{d(x,y):x\ne y\in X\}$ is dense in $\Bbb R^+$ for each $x\in X.$

Comment: What is a conical embedding?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Just something intuitive.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Maybe we use different notation. Thanks.

Comment: It has become standard that $A\subset A$.  But  any notation is ok as long as we understand each other.  ... & what is a canonical embedding? Do you mean an  isometric (distance-preserving ) embedding?